# bootstrap 3.x not show h4 and icon in inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to list title with icon and description using bootstrap 3.X. But in action `<h4>` and `<i>` not display in `inline`.

HTML:

```
<div class="mil-product">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="title"><span class="so"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-2x"></i> <h4> Title of</h4></span></div>
      <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>Description Description Description Description </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="title"><span class="so"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-2x"></i><h4> Title Of 2</h4></span></div>
      <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>Description Description Description Description</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="title"><span class="so"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-2x"></i><h4> Title Of 3</h4></span></div>
      <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></i>Description Description Description Description</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .mil-product > ul > li > div.title {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
  }

  .mil-product > ul > li > div.title > .so {
    color: #a0a0a0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: auto;
  }

  .mil-product > ul > li > span.desc {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
```

DEMO [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/04magL2L/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h4` is default block element so it will tend to go down in new line. We need to make it inline

```
h4 {
    display: inline-block; /* to make it inline */
    vertical-align: middle /* to align it vertically other values are top | bottom | baseline */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css

```
h4 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

h4 have a default "display: block" property. 
When you need to align any other content in position relative with it you need to change it.

So solution is to add these lines in your css :

```
  h4 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Care, sometime you need to add "vertical-align: top/middle/whatever..." to make them having a vertical alignment.
Simple :)